# ImageJ: When making an image binary, how do I ensure that adjoining cells are not connected? (not watershed)

Tags: imagej

I am attempting to count cells that have irregular shapes. After making the image binary, some cells are connected and become a huge blob. As a result, with particle analysis, many neighbouring cells are counted as one. *Watershed does not work* in this case, as the cells do not have similar shapes and many single cells become divided into many segments.
My best attempt so far is to minimize the background noise before turning the image binary. But is there another way?

Thank you in advance,

KL

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the [Trainable Weka Segmentation](http://fiji.sc/Trainable_Weka_Segmentation) plugin? It is part of the [Fiji distribution of ImageJ](http://fiji.sc/).

Answer (score 0):

another Option for Segmentation is the Foci Picker 3D http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/plugins/foci-picker3d/index.html